# Why was the keygen tag removed from HTML5?

Tags: google, html, tags

Why was the  tag considered a bad API and removed from the HTML specification?  This article on Google's developers site says so (the other links are just related materials):

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate#removing-apis

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen
  - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html
  - https://whatwg.org/faq#removing-bad-ideas

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the page you [linked to answers the question](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate#removing-apis) "...requiring extensive telemetry to quantify how many web pages would have their behavior changed. But when the feature is sufficiently insecure, is harmful to users, or is used very rarely, this can be done."

Comment: Wait.. what? Keygen was a standard tag that wasn't implemented by MooTools..

Comment: What you quoted is talking about whether or not it's _possible_ to remove a feature.. not why the <keygen> tag was removed..

Comment: Looks like browsers just removed support for it.. not sure why. 

https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2079